# Why does not FancyBox.js work in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, popup, fancybox

I've written such code in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")      
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert("H");
            $('#gallery a').fancybox({
            });

        });  // end ready
    </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="gallery" >   
        <a href="../../Content/Images/Slide1.JPG" rel="gallery" title="Img1!:)">
            <img alt="Dog" height="170" src="../../Content/Images/Slide1_s.JPG" width="200" /></a>
        <a href="../../Content/Images/Slide2.JPG" rel="gallery" title="Img2!:)">
            <img alt="Cat" height="170" src="../../Content/Images/Slide2_s.JPG" width="200" /></a>
      </div>            
    </body>
```

I've used above code in simple html file and it works perfectly. However, if I try to put this code in MVC 4, it does not work. Just links of images work and it shows just image without "new pop-up window". I checked a lot of times all addresses of ".js" libraries and putted "alert('Hello from .js')" to check availability from "Scripts" folder of these libraries.

What's the reason of that? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved "@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")" and "@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)" from    to  and it works perfectly!

The whole code is:

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />        
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)             
    <link href="~/Icon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
```